# Apply different styles depending on whether the field is empty or not

Tags: javascript, material-ui, textfield

I have a fairly simple text field (TextField) on my site. When the user enters a value into it, a site search is performed.

My question is: is it possible to apply different styles to a TextField depending on whether the field is currently empty or whether the user has entered some value.

In my case, I would like to set the bounds of the TextField to green if the field is not empty (regardless of whether the cursor is on the input field or not)

```
    const CssTextField = withStyles({
    root: {
      '& label.Mui-focused': {
        color: '#1062de',
      },
      '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
        borderBottomColor: '#1062de',
      },
      '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
        '& fieldset': {
          borderColor: 'black',
        },
        '&:hover fieldset': {
          borderColor: 'black',
        },
        '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
          borderColor: '#1062de',
        },
      },
    },
  })(TextField);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty, simple and performant solution. It lies within CSS and nothing else.

HTML/JSX:

```
<input type="text" minlength="1" required>
```

CSS:

```
[type="text"]:valid {
border-color: red;
}
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But it doesn't work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Could you show me with an example of my code